# Centrar icono al espacio disponible en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Quiero crear un layout para los elementos de `grid` así de forma de regilla, su base es un icono, titulo y total

Ahora lo que tengo es más o menos como la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="Favorites" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/size"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="12" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Lo que no me sale**

El icono ahora está centrado a la totalidad de la caja, lo que necesito que el icono se centre solo lo que ocupa el espacio blanco.

Comment: Osea, que ocupe todo el espacio en blanco?

Comment: Creo que pasa porque a la imagen le has dicho android:layout_centerInParent="true" y eso es que la centre en el padre que es la tarjeta (cardView). Dentro de la tarjeta, deberías crear 2 layout, uno para el hueco en blanco y otro para la zona inferior. En el layout del hueco en blanco, metes la imagen. Ahora el padre de la imagen es ese layout nuevo, así que lo debería posicionar en el centro del hueco en blanco

Comment: @Einer si que centre en el espacio en blanco, ahora me centra en su totalidad

Comment: Me estoy mirando lo de layout_weight que creo que es una solución

Comment: Si, probablemente. Intentalo y nos cuentas. Cualquier cosa nos informas si necesitas algo.

Answer (score 1):

El final lo he conseguido ajustando los espacios con `android:layout_weight`

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_menu_manage" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="Favorites" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/summary"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="start"
                tools:text="12" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```